# How to initialize a vector with values 0 to n?

Tags: vector, rust

How do I initialize a vector from `0` to `n` in Rust? Is there another way of doing that than creating an empty vector and invoking `push` inside a loop?

I prefer a one-liner.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A [range](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.Range.html) can be [collected](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) into a vector:

```
pub fn sequence(n: u32) -> Vec<u32> {
    (0..n).collect()
}
```

<sup>[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a627db89917d2d84b754e4b1c5bf5f45)</sup>

Comment: Nicer (IMO): `Vec::from_iter(0..n)`

Comment: Both solutions are nice and save me three lines of code :) I'll have to think a bit about which one I prefer...

Comment: I think you'll see `collect()` used more often than `from_iter()` because it can just be tacked on existing iterator chains, but functionally they do the same thing.

Comment: @kmdreko There is actually a difference: `collect()` needs an `Iterator`, while `FromIterator::from_iter()` takes an `IntoIterator`. Ranges are `Iterator`s thus it doesn't matter, but for arrays, for example, it's `[1, 2, 3].into_iter().collect::<Vec<_>>()` vs. `Vec::from_iter([1, 2, 3])` which is a bigger difference.

Comment: @kmdreko And since `FromIterator` is in the prelude since edition 2021, I'd expect much more usages of it (I use it more now, and I also saw that in other people's code). It's just shorter when you don't perform any transformation on the iterable, just converting to to another container: `Container::from_iter(v)` instead of `v.into_iter().collect::<Container>()`.

Answer (score 6):

Here is how you can do it as a one-liner:

```
let n = 4;

let v: Vec<i32> = (0..n).collect();  // the last element will be n-1
assert_eq!(v, vec![0, 1, 2, 3]);

let v: Vec<i32> = (0..=n).collect();  // the last element will be n
assert_eq!(v, vec![0, 1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

Or, alternatively:

```
let v: Vec<i32> = Vec::from_iter(0..n);  // the last element will be n-1
assert_eq!(v, vec![0, 1, 2, 3]);

let v: Vec<i32> = Vec::from_iter(0..=n);  // the last element will be n
assert_eq!(v, vec![0, 1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

Instead of `i32` we could use other numeric types like `u8`, `u16`, `i8`, etc. That's because both [`collect()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) and [`Vec::from_iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html) are [generic](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-01-syntax.html) methods.

All those solutions make use of the [Range](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.Range.html) or [RangeInclusive](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.RangeInclusive.html) structs respectively, both of which implement [Iterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html). That allows them to easily be converted into a [Vec](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html), which is most often done via the `collect()` method.